# Scroll webpage when paper-dropdown-menu opened

Tags: html, css, sass, polymer

I'm trying to scroll the page when the paper-dropdown-menu opened. Without clicking outside of the paper-dropdown-menu how to scroll the page?

Answer (score 0):

According to [component source code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu/blob/master/paper-dropdown-menu.js#L164) you need to set `allowOutsideScroll="true"`. Didn't test it may refer to different scrolling.